# Exponential regression

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function, regression

I am trying to figure out a way to get the function parameters from the different points of an exponential function $f(x)=ab^x + c$.  I figured it out for $f(x) = ab^x$, but can't find the answer when the function contains $c$.
So I need to solve for $a$,$b$ and $c$ in the system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
ab^{x_1} + c = y_1\\
ab^{x_2} + c = y_2\\
ab^{x_3} + c = y_3\\
\end{aligned}\right.$$

I was able to reduce the equation to one unknown: $\frac{b^{x_1}-b^{x_2}}{b^{x_2}-b^{x_3}} = \frac{y_1-y_2}{y_2-y_3}$
I don't know how to solve for $b$ in this equation and I have tried solving for other variables, which all didn't work. Is this system of equations even solvable? All help is appreciated.
Please excuse my bad formatting, I don't know how to type math equations.

Comment: are you free to calculate $f(0), f(1), f(2)$?

Comment: You are given three arbitrary points, you can't choose the x or y coordinates.

Comment: You probably need to solve this numerically. You can solve for $c$ by trial and error, by plotting $log(y_i - v)$ versus $x_i$ and then changing $v$ until all 3 points are on a straight line, either eyeballing, or computing.

Comment: The parameters $a,b,c$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of standard functions ( i.e. : not solvable analitically). Approximate solution can be computed with numerical method of calculus. This is quite  the same for  more than three points : the equation can easily be approximately fitted thanks to non-linear regression.

Comment: How would you approcimate a,b and c ? Sorry, I'm not familiar with solving numerically.

Comment: @user_31415926535 I can show you how to solve numerically with the R programming language, if you want.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am not familiar with R I only know Python, but thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I found I solution for the equation for when the space between the different x values is the same, I think that'll do it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment that you are familiar with Python. Here is how to numerically solve this system of nonlinear equations with Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

x1 = 2
y1 = 7
x2 = 4
y2 = 19
x3 = 6
y3 = 67

# for a given variable w, this function returns F(w)
# if w is the solution of the nonlinear system, then 
# F(w)=0
# with your notations, w = [a, b, c]
def nonlinearEquation(w):
    F = np.zeros(3)
    F[0] = w[0]*w[1]**x1 + w[2] - y1
    F[1] = w[0]*w[1]**x2 + w[2] - y2
    F[2] = w[0]*w[1]**x3 + w[2] - y3
    return F

# generate an initial guess of the solution
initialGuess = np.random.rand(3)    
 
# solve the problem    
solutionInfo = fsolve(nonlinearEquation, initialGuess, full_output=1)
```

See [here](https://aleksandarhaber.com/solve-systems-of-nonlinear-equations-in-python-by-using-fsolve/) for details. The solution of the system is returned in the first component of `solutionInfo`.

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The headline of your query is **"Exponential regression"** what smells like *overdetermined system*, more equations than unkown vars. But then you present three equations and ask if this is solvable for a,b and c. Sure it is.

According your description you already solved for a and c. In that case I'd suggest to change the origingal function $f(x)=ab^x+c$ to $g(x)=f(x)-c=ab^x$. Thus your modified equation system is now $$\displaystyle y_i - c = a\cdot b^x_i$$ Taking the log of it gives $$log(y_i - c) = log(a) + x\cdot log(b)$$ what is pretty linear and NP that way.
**But...** what if any $y_i\le c$? Well, in that case call *Houston, we have a problem*

Comment: Yes, my goal is exponential regression if that works without solving this system of equations that would be great, but I don't know a method other than this. Also I didn't say I solved for a and c, I said I solved for the simpler case when $f(x) = ab^x$.

Comment: _"Regression"_ implies, you have more data than needed to solve it directly. The method is to apply the principle of least squares (claimed by Carl Gauss to be his idea). This is the first *know-why tessera* of regression, the know-how part is to use a ready-to-use software or apt pocket calculator.